# Bypassing Invisible ReCaptcha on an Angular Web App

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, recaptcha, puppeteer

I'm trying to bypass ReCaptcha on an Angular Web App.
I use a solving captcha API that will return the response after solving it by an human but I don't know how to submit this token I get back...

Where should I look for the submit function that gets executed at the end of the process since there's no submit button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to know where to look.

Look at the source code, or somewhere on the elements panel on browser, Know how to put invisible recaptcha on your website. By doing so you will also know how to use the proper callback.

Most invisible recaptcha has `callback=` and class `g-recaptcha` on the form. Look here,

```
<form id="simpleForm" action="backEndServiceUrl" method="POST">
  <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="yourKey" data-callback="onSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It changes from one way to another to prevent bots, and maybe my answer right now will also impact this.

You can set the value to this element,

```
document.querySelector("#g-recaptcha-response").value
```

And call the callback `onSubmit`.

All these will stop working once google patches their anti-captcha system once again.

Tested above with few anti-captcha providers just to make sure it still works when I'm answering this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've found a function called "submitForm(myForm.$valid)" but when I try to run it it says undefined function... Any ideas ?

Comment: how about `document.querySelector('#simpleForm').submit()` ? ;)

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher did they patch this ? i used to find the callback somewhere like `___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].L.L.callback`  but recently this is empty

Comment: I think there are few more invisible captcha than before. Even cloudflare changed to hcaptcha as well.